# object loaded by http not bounded

Tags: angular

Im new to Angular2 and right now I'm trying to build a simple app that displays a list of objects. From there I want click through to a detailed view of one object. When I do so and want to access one of the objects' properties I get an exception:

`cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

This is the code I'm using:

my service looks like this (based on the tutorial found on the angular site):

```
getQuotation(id: number): Observable<Quotation> {
    return this.http.get(this.quotationUrl)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
  };

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    return res.json();
  }

  private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
```

The http.get call points to a static json file that looks like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "string",
  "email": "string",
  "date": "string",
  "quotationStatus": "string",
  "read": true
}
```

and seems loaded correctly if I write the res.json() to the console.

The quotation component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; import {QuotationService} from "./quotation.service";

@Component({   
    templateUrl: './quotation.component.html',   
    styleUrls: ['./quotation.component.css'],   
    providers: [QuotationService] 
}) export class QuotationComponent implements OnInit {   

  constructor(private quotationService : QuotationService) { }

  quotation : Quotation;   
  errorMessage : string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.quotationService.getQuotation(1)
        .subscribe(
            quotation => this.quotation = quotation,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error,
        );   
    } 
}

export class Quotation {   
    id: number;   
    name: string;   
    email: string;   
    date: string;   
    quotationStatus: string;   
    read: boolean; 
}
```

And the template looks like this:

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="columns small-12">
            <h1>Offerte # {{ quotation.id }}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

If I leave out the {{ quotation.id }} part the template is loaded without any error.

Any help would be appreciated since this is already taking too much time to fix and I'm starting to get frustrated :).

**EDIT**

Just to be clear. I don't want to hide the exception, I want the quotation to be loaded and have to understand why it is not right now.

Comment: Try `{{quotation?.id}}`

Comment: safe navigation operator is not to "hide exeption", but rather to safeguard null values, while we wait for data to be retrieved. If when you use the safe navigation operator and the data is not shown, it means that the quotation is actually undefined. You have to check that you are receiving data correctly. The code you have provided looks fine to me, so there must be something going on upon retrieval of data...

Comment: @AJT_82 Thanks for the explanation. Seems like I still have a lot to learn. Good to know the code itself is not the problem. At least I can exclude some causes :)

Comment: No problem :) Have you checked that you are getting data at all?

Comment: Yeah, I already managed to fix it. Not sure what really fixed it, but suddenly the id field appeared.

Comment: Maybe it was magic? :D Well great that it got fixed, have nice weekend! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:-

## safe Navigation operator

```
<div class="columns small-12">
            <h1>Offerte # {{ quotation?.id }}</h1>
        </div>
```

Comment: I think my question was not clear enough, but I don't want to hide the exception, I want to solve the exception. So the quotation.id should be loaded and displayed.